# Como fazer um find com Paginação e termo de busca ao mesmo tempo com Spring data?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Olá, minha dúvida é a seguinte. 
Quero fazer uma pesquisa passando um PageRequest e um Objeto ou alguns termos de busca e receber uma lista de volta. 
Por exemplo:

List getList(PageRequest page,Pessoa pessoa);

Nesse caso quero que a busca retorne os registros referentes aos seus respetivos campos de Pessoa (fazendo um like com cada um dos campos).

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço isso usando spring-data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você quer usar todos os atributos do objeto de tipo `Pessoa`, umas das formas é usar *[Query by Example (QBE)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)*, então a primeira coisa que deve fazer para facilitar é herdar também do *executor* `QueryByExampleExecutor` em seu *repository*. Nele terá métodos que criarão consultas dinâmicas de acordo com os atributos do objeto.

Teríamos um *repository* parecido com isto:

```java
public interface PessoaRepository extends CrudRepository<Pessoa, Long>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Pessoa> {}
```

Um exemplo de uso seria algo assim:

```java
final Pessoa pessoa = ...;
final Example<Pessoa> example = Example.of(pessoa);
final Page<Pessoa> result = repository.findAll(example, pageRequest);
```

Outras formas de uso é alterar o retorno para um [`Slice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) ou [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) e não um [`Page`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html), além das formas [assíncronas](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async), daí basta em seu *repository* escrever um método de consulta como este:

```java
Slice<Pessoa> findPessoaByExample(final Example<Pessoa> example, final Pageable page);
```

Agora, usando apenas alguns atributos do objeto, você teria um repositório sem herdar também de `QueryByExampleExecutor`, assim:

```java
public interface PessoaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Pessoa, Long> {}
```

Um exemplo de método de consulta seria isto:

```java
 Page<Pessoa> findByNomeIgnoreCaseAndIdade(final String nome, final Integer idade, final Pageable page);
```

Assumindo que no tipo `Pessoa` existem tais atributos:

```java
@Entity
public Pessoa {

    private String nome;

    private Integer idade;

}
```

Veja que neste caso a consulta aumentaria sempre que precisasse de um novo atributo na consulta. Você pode também usar alguma outra extensão como [`Query DSL`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl), que ajuda também consulta dinâmicas através de seus predicados.

Independente da forma de uso garanta sempre que seu objeto `Pageable` seja o último parâmetro do *method repository*, este é o padrão usado pelo Spring para instropecção de *queries*. Além disto, para os exemplos considerei JPA, se for outro tipo de persistência avise, pode ser que tenha, mas usando o comum do *spring data* funciona em outros tipos de persistência.